# [Genexus} What's the code behind de Network.IsServerAvailable() function?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I've been trying to use the isServerAvailable function in SD, it works fine when I run it on my local environment or when I use it in an emulator connected to the remote test server, via vpn installed on my pc. But it fails (returns false) when I try it on mobile phone (against the remote test server, via vpn installed on the phone). So I want to know what's the code behind the function so I can detect if the test server is blocking a specific request.

Answer (score 0):

The function IsServerAvailable() check for a valid internet connection in the device and if has any try to reach the server.
There was an issue in Android with VPN connections that were not detected in Gx v17, that was solved in v17u1

Can you check if your problem is the same? SAC #48472 :

https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=48472;;

Tks,